# Jquery multiple accordions on same page with text triggers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I need to have 4 separate divs(areas) on my page. and in each of those 4 areas i have a list.
The lists need to be accordions. They don't use the default h3 header as the trigger, the trigger needs to be a text link right below each list that says "Expand +".

So when you click on "Expand+" in the corresponding div the list will appear. Then "Expand+" will turn into "Close-"

All the accordions need to be closed at the start.

Is this possible with jqueryUI and accordion?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Please refer to the following options on the [`accordion`](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/) documentation.

> [`active`](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active): Which panel is currently open. Setting `active` to false will collapse all panels. This requires the `collapsible` option to be true.
>
> [`header`](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-header): Selector for the header element, applied via `.find()` on the main accordion element. Content panels must be the sibling immedately after their associated headers.

However, you will need to write some bespoke code in order to handle the text change.

An example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/dP5mn/

Comment: would accordion even be the right ul element to use for this?

Comment: If you want accordion-like behaviour for your lists, then yes. Although using `<dl>` lists would probably be better suited for accordions. I've added an example to the answer to demonstrate.